# How to get rid of Ionic vertical scroll bar on a blank project?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I create a new blank project using Ionic CLI, the Home page appears with a vertical scroll bar. How to get rid of it?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

to your `app.scss` file to override it everywhere.